# With Git, how can I pull, but without causing a merge?

Tags: git, github, commit, pull

I have created a new commit, but forgot to pull before that. (I should have used `git stash`and than `git pull`.) Now if I `git pull`, I get an additional commit "merge origin/<branch> to <branch>" (Some commits have already been pushed by some other colleagues.), which I don't want.

Is there any way to do `git pull` without merging?

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed you, but if you want to put your commit on top of what the others pushed to origin/branch you can pull with --rebase option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git pull` is essentially `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, so if you want a pull without the merge, just do `git fetch`.

Answer (score 4):

If you already did that commit accidentially, then follow this workflow:

- Create a new branch from the current branch (basically for making a "safety copy" of your commit).
- Reset your current branch to the commit before your commit ("deleting" the commit).
- Pull.
- Cherry-pick your commit from the backup branch to your current branch, delete the backup branch afterwards.

Comment: or just use `git pull --rebase` as explained here: http://marketblog.envato.com/general/rebasing-merge-commits-in-git/

Answer (score 3):

All you need is `git pull --rebase`