# Tortoise Git - lost commits after a pull resulted in conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

This SO question perfectly describes our situation:
[What is the right way to commit/push when there are conflicts in Git or TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077616/what-is-the-right-way-to-commit-push-when-there-are-conflicts-in-gittortoise-gi)

There is no answer (atleast not one that is accepted) on the above question.

This seems to be one of the solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12171221/172396

However I think that's an overkill. I just lost a commit to my colleagues. Git being a distributed VCS, I thought it would be okay if we advise colleagues to make local commits and then push to a central repo once or twice a day. Most of the time, they are working on separate modules, and won't cause a conflict. On occasional conflicts, I thought we can always resolve locally and then make another local commit and remote push.

Now a colleague committed locally and was trying to push resulting in a conflict. She pulled, resolved conflicts and then ONLY pushed her changed files. The remote repo had another commit saying merge branch with some files that is effectively undoing my commits earlier.

Is this expected? How are we supposed to work locally and then re-sync once in a while.
If I have committed locally, and a subsequent pull results in a conflict, how do I ensure I merge correctly so I don't undo previous commits on the remote repo.

Comment: I can probably answer your question, I just need to test out a few things first. You can help by providing an example workflow, with git commands, that demonstrates what caused your current problem. Also, although git allows you to sync with your coworkers occasionally, it's actually better to sync as frequently as possible, in order to reduce both the likelihood of conflicts, as well as the severity of any conflicts that do occur. At my last job, I used to sync my local branches with other people's work several times an hour, throughout the day.

Comment: Related, but not quite a duplicate: [How do I fix merge conflicts in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161813/how-do-i-fix-merge-conflicts-in-git).

Comment: Did you need help fixing this as well? Not sure if that should be it's own question. I guess I can add even more to my current answer.

Comment: If you need help fixing the merge commit, it will help to see your current commit graph. Add the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate` to your question. You can scramble the commit shas and messages if you want, if they contain sensitive information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to address your questions line by line:

> On occasional conflicts, I thought we can always resolve locally and then make
>   another local commit and remote push.

Yes, that's correct.

> Now a colleague committed locally and was trying to push resulting in a
>   conflict. She pulled, resolved conflicts and then ONLY pushed her changed files.
>   The remote repo had another commit saying merge branch with some files that is
>   effectively undoing my commits earlier. Is this expected?

Yes, it's expected (i.e. I'm not surprised), though that doesn't mean that what
your coworker did was correct. **Your coworker basically threw away all the work
you did previously with that mege commit.** I shall explain.

When git detects conflicts that it can't figure out how to auto-resolve during
an attempted merge, it aborts the merge midway, ***leaving un-conflicted files
added to your staging area***, and leaving conflicted files with conflict
markers ***un-staged*** in your working copy.

For example, this is what a merge that results in conflicts looks like from the
command line:

```
git status

On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   hello.txt

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        both modified:      foo.txt
```

Notice that git has automatically staged `hello.txt` to be committed, because it
doesn't have any conflicts. I haven't used TortoiseGit in over 1.5+ years, but
if my memory serves me correctly, ***staged files are represented in TortoiseGit
with checked-checkboxes***, which means you want to commit those files.

***Un-checking those automatically-staged checkboxes is incorrect***, in this
case. It basically means that you don't want to commit those file changes that
you've just merged in from the other branch (or in your case, from the upstream
`remote/origin`). It's essentially throwing away the work that was done on those
files.

The correct way to merge, in this case, would be to resolve the conflicted
files, and then add them to the staging area to be committed, ***along with all
the other file changes that are already there***, even if you were not
originally responsible for those changes.

> How are we supposed to work locally and then re-sync once in a while.

That's up to how you and your team want to organize your workflow.

> If I have committed locally, and a subsequent pull results in a conflict, how
>   do I ensure I merge correctly so I don't undo previous commits on the remote
>   repo.

Unless you have a good reason not to, as I've already said, you usually want to
commit all the files, even if you weren't originally reponsible for the changes
to them. Not doing so essentially means that you don't actually want to keep
those changes.

Comment: Hi cupcake, if a pull resulted in a conflict, after resolving the conflict; if I were to just execute git merge, would Git merge all the remaining files starting from exactly where Git aborted the merge on conflict?

Comment: @r_honey I recommend that you read the last section of [Pro Git: 3.2 Git Branching - Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/ch3-2.html#Basic-Merge-Conflicts), I think that might help you. Also keep in mind that you can always create a small test repo with a text file to test these kinds of things out.

Comment: @r_honey sorry, was this in the context of using git from the command line, or through TortoiseGit?

Comment: @r_honey sorry, I stopped using TortoiseGit almost 2 years ago, I just use the command line now. Just test it out on a test repo and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone's benefit, this is the strategy that I have resorted to that seems to work well for us.

1. If a Git pull, results in a conflict, resolve the conflict locally.
2. Ensure there are no remaining files that are conflicted.
3. Do a Git pull again.
4. Goto Step 2 if you again get a conflict.

Basically you try to resove conflicts and do a Git pull and keep on doing this until a Git pull completes successfully with no conflicts (effectively meaning your commit head now is updated to the remote commit head).

A change of mindset is needed when addressing conflicts if you are coming from a SVN background.
In SVN, a merge conflict during an update does not abort the SVN update process. SVN client would still update your local copy to the latest remote revision. Only individual files would be left in conflicted state that you can resolve (and commit back if needed).

So a conflict still means all local files that were not conflicted are up--to-date with the remote repo after an update.

In Git, a conflict during pull simply terminates/aborts the update process. So if the remote repo had 10 commits that need to be pulled, and you get a conflict when Git was pulling (and merging) the 3rd of these commits, effectively the process is aborted. 8 of the remote commits are NOT in your local repo (note the remote commit that caused a conflict also isn't merged successfully, so its 8 commits that are not synced locally and not 7).

You resolve conflicts and keep doing a git pull until successful thus preventing you from overwriting other commits. To provide a bit more details from what I have understood about git, a push without resolving the conflict would cause the remote branch's commit head to be relocated incorrectly. e.g. suppose you need to pull 4 revisions from a Git repo:

```
A - B - C - D
            |- commit head
```

Now suppose you get a conflict while pulling and merging Revision B. If you do a push now to remote (without resolving the conflicts and doing a git pull until successful), the remote repo now looks like this:

```
A - B - C - D
    |- E - commit head
```

So effectively although commits C/D exist remotely, they won't be a part of your build based on the branch's commit head.
If you follow @CupCake's advice and push the remaining files, commits C/D become a part of commit E sort of. So that doesn't impact your correctness of the build.
But if you don't push those files after conflict which you don't changed but Git was showing as modified (because you did not resolve the conflict and completed a successful git pull), then effectievly you are leading to lost commits.